# Запретить скачивание .git/index

Tags: git, nginx

У *nginx* есть уязвимость, которая позволяет просмотреть папки в `.git`. https://habr.com/ru/post/422725/

В статье пишется, что можно починить это путем написания:

```
location ~ /\.(?!git\/) {
    deny all;
}
```

Написал. Но тем не менее если обратиться по адресу `http://mysite/.git/index`, то файлик `index` скачивается без проблем. Можно ли как-то запретить скачивание этого файла?

Comment: Очевидно, это не уязвимость, а фича - вы же сами настраиваете nginx на раздачу файлов из такого-то каталога. Самое правильное решение - просто не хранить `.git` в тех каталогах, которые раздаёт nginx, и тогда читать `.git/index` будет тупо неоткуда.

Comment: @andreymal а если мне нужно подтянуть изменения в проект из гита? Я же не могу .git вынести вне потому что он будет лежать в корне сайтов и в репу будут складироваться они

Comment: локейшн выглядит правильно, не понятно зачем скобки. `location ~ /\.git { deny all; }` короче. А причин, почему таки скачивается index, может быть несколько, например, более приоритетный location - в регулярках это более длинное выражение. Покажите весь конфиг.

Comment: регулярное выражение запрещает обращения к url, начинающимся с точки, но разрешает обращения к url, начинающимся с `.git/`. это явная ошибка (опечатка?) и вопрос следует закрыть с соответствующей формулировкой.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Нужно сделать, чтобы `http://mysite/` указывал не в корень, где лежит `.git` (кстати, зачем хранить на сервере весь репозиторий?), а в подпапку, которая лежит рядом с `.git`.

Сейчас примерно так:

```
root
   |- .git
   |- folder1
   |- folder2
   |- index.html
```

И запрос на http://mysite/ указывает на `root`. А нужно сделать так:

```
root
   |- .git
   |- site
         |-folder1
         |- folder2
         |- index.html
```

чтобы запрос на http://mysite/ указывал на `site` (или `www` или как там еще назовете).

Comment: А если у меня несколько сайтов? Все лежат в /var/www?

Comment: А на что это влияет?

Comment: Ну как. так у меня  в гите был один сайт, который я могу обновлять из гита в необходимый момент. а так у меня в гит будут затягиваться все сайты: site, site2, site3 и т.д.

Comment: Почему бы и нет? Ну и если не хочется, то против этого придуман .gitignore.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что каждый сайт может содержать `.git`, чтобы подтягивать изменения на конкретный сайт? Потому что один сайт - один проект. А при таком подходе всё это нельзя реализовать.

Comment: Ну добавьте еще один уровень папок, делов то.

Comment: Зачем вам вообще папка .git на сервере?

Comment: "чтобы подтягивать изменения"

Comment: @СергейМишин, "чтобы подтягивать изменения" нужны совсем другие программы. например, rsync.

Answer (score 1):

заглянул таки в статью, на которую вы ссылаетесь. что, мол, за бред люди пишут.

ан нет, там советуют верно:

```
location ~ /\.(?!well-known\/) { deny all; }
```

т.е.: запретить все url, начинающиеся с точки, но разрешить начинающиеся с `/.well-known/` (очевидно — для обработки запросов от *letsencrypt*). вы же поставили всё с ног на голову:

```
location ~ /\.(?!git\/) { deny all; }
```

явно разрешаете обращения к `/.git/`.

---

если доступ к url, начинающимся с `/.well-known/`, вам не требуется, то уж лучше запретите обращения к url, начинающимся просто с точки:

```
location ~ /\. { deny all; }
```

ну или хотя бы просто с `/.git` (без слэша в конце — пусть и файлы типа `.gitignore` не раздаются, раз уж вы «плывёте против течения», используя git-хранилище прямо в каталоге, доступном http-серверу):

```
location ~ /\.git { deny all; }
```

Comment: ну да, когда я прочитал "well-known" и перевел как "общеизвестный", я решил что это такой намёк, что всем же известно как пишется git и это такой намёк. Но `location ~ /\.git { deny all; }` всё равно не работает. Видимо настройки сервака совсем плохие.  Я не понимаю почему это не работает