# Как производится процесс "залития" измененных файлов на боевой сервер?

Tags: веб-программирование, версионирование, release-management

Предположим у вас есть несколько разрабатываемых проектов для разных заказчиков. И задачи

1. Залить готовый проект
2. Заливать фиксы, изменения, заказанные фичи в дальнейшем

Вручную постоянно это делать глупо. Я хотел это делать с помощью гита. Но мне [сказали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1012634/#comment1719212_1012644), что

> "чтобы подтягивать изменения" нужны совсем другие программы. например, rsync.

Так ли это? А чем гит не угодил?

Как поступают в современной разработке, когда нужно заливать готовый проект, релизы и фиксы с фичами заказчику?

---

P.S. Поставьте пожалуйста корректные метки к вопросу - я не знаю к чему его отнести

Comment: из git нужно людям доставать и делать все руками на стороне заказчика. А rsync просто поставит все на место сразу

Comment: @maint то есть если я буду иметь доступ к ПК заказчика и являюсь ответственным за эти обновления - то разницы нет? А вообще как люди поступают-то в итоге?

Comment: в итоге используют rsync